# Right design of my application - is inheritance right choice?

Tags: inheritance, oop

I have some simple scheduling of various events in my application and I used this class hierarchy:

```
abstract class ScheduledEvent
{
    public DateTime When{ get; set; }

    public abstract void Trigger();
}

class WhateverEvent : ScheduledEvent
{
  public override void Trigger();
}

class AnotherEvent : ScheduledEvent
{
  public override void Trigger();
}

class Scheduler
{
  public AddEvent(ScheduledEvent event)
}
```

My application works fine but I don't like the design because whenever I want to add a new event I have to add a new descendant to the hierarchy and all books say *prefer composition over inheritance* so I tried this approach:

```
interface ITriggerable
{
    void Trigger();
}

class WhateverEvent : ITriggerable
{
  public void Trigger();
}

abstract class ScheduledEvent
{
    private ITriggerable triggerable;
    public ScheduledEvent(ITriggerable t) { 
        triggerable = t; 
    }
    public DateTime When{ get; set; }

    public void Trigger() { triggerable.Trigger(); }
}
```

But problem occurred immediately. For every type of event there was a form for editing of its properties like this:

```
class WhateverForm : Form
{
    WhateveverForm(WhateverEvent ev) { ... }
}
```

This form had available all properties of `WhateverEvent` and also property `When` of `ScheduledEvent`. With my new hierarchy this property is not available anymore. I can of course add reference to `ScheduledEvent` to `WhateverEvent` but I don't like it.

My question is how would you design your class hierarchy and why? It may seem trivial for you but I don't have much real experience with design and I want to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

I think the old design using inheritance is perfectly fine, and less complicated. You're using polymorphism the way it is supposed to be used.

My interpretation of *"prefer composition over inheritance"* is (roughly) that if you don't need polymorphic behavior, then you should use composition instead of inheritance.

With the ITriggerable approach, you're not solving the problem of having to write a subclass for every new event. You're just using an interface instead of a base class. It's not *technically* inheritance, but it's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I won't know what's the best for you, but a good design needs to provide [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)) while balance the amount of [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) and [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)). I wouldn't follow the any rule which favours composition over inheritance too closely. There are reasons for either design decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell with just random names like this. Subclasses should follow the 'is a' rule: say `Truck` is a subclass of `Vehicle`, then a `truck` should **be a** `vehicle`.

But don't get too carried away, either - think about code reuse most of all, and don't just create a deep hierarchy because you can, only create it if it will lead to simpler code, better encapsulation and more code reuse.

Answer (score 0):

The advice to prefer composition over inheritance concerns how one should approach achieving reuse.  Composition provides both the ability to reuse data and/or behavior across different class hierarchies as well as the ability to substitute the particular behavior of a type at run time.  Composition doesn't eliminate the need to create new types for different behavior.

Concerning a model for scheduling, the approach I've taken in the past was to separate the concepts of task, schedule, schedule monitor, and scheduling service.  In my case, I needed schedule to encapsulate more than just a fixed point in time, so it contained additional properties for specifying recurrence interval, recurrence count, etc.  I did not encapsulate the schedule within the task because tasks aren't something that are inherently concerned with when they occur.For example, an *oil change* is a task while *every 3 months* is a schedule which may be applied to oil changes as well as other maintenance tasks.  By separating schedule from task, a single monitor could be maintained for multiple tasks which happened to share the same schedule.